# Does Excel Add-In VSTO 2005SE Need Manifest Files?

Tags: excel, add-in, manifest

We developed application level Excel Add-In in Visual Studio 2005 using VSTO 2005SE. The add-in installs and works fine on Excel 2003, 2007 and 2010 (32-bit) on the most of computers. However, in some cases Excel does not load it, despite the fact the registry LoadBehaviour (LB) value is set to 3 during the installation. When the user un-installs the add-in the LB is still set to 3, so I assume there is no error happens during initialization and loading, otherwise LB will be 2 or even 1.

We use MSI installation and deploy the add-in on application level with Local Machine registry keys. 
When we build the add-in in Visual Studio 2005 there is no manifest files generated, so we don’t include these files in our MSI installation and there is no registry key entry for the manifest. So, we assumed the manifest is not essential part.

Even more, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a3swb498(v=vs.80) the application manifest provides information that is used by an Office solution to locate and update its assemblies. Since we have only one assembly that is a solution, we don’t need any manifest.

Our MSI file, add-in assembly and setup.exe files are signed with the COMODO certificate.

Does anyone know if we need an application and deployment manifests and if so how can we generate ones?